# Mostrar un div sólo en landscape

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy mostrando un div oculto `#alert` cuando `#total=0`, y lo que estoy buscando es que `#alert` **SÓLO se muestre** cuando la pantalla está en landscape.

El problema es que **aunque en el CSS** hay un `@media screen` el script lo ignora y siempre me muestra el div `#alert` a cualquier resolución de pantalla y en cualquier orientación, y la verdad es que no sé solucionarlo correctamente.

¿Cuál es el fragmento del script que debería agregar para evaluar si la pantalla **está sólo en horizontal y hasta 999px** ántes de mostrar el div `#alert` para un `#total=0` ...?

Éste es mi código (también disponible en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba860swy/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function manageRegalo() {

    var totalStorage = Number(localStorage.getItem("total"));
    var total = parseFloat($("#total").val());

    if (totalStorage != null && total === 0) {
      total = totalStorage;
    }

    if (total > 99.99 && total < 299.99) {
      console.log("PASS");
      $('#regalo').show();
      $('#alert').hide();

      if (localStorage.getItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1') == null) {
        $('.tooltip').show();
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 2000);

        //--------------------

        if (!$("#notify")[0].paused) { //play audio
          $("#notify")[0].pause(); //play audio
          $("#notify")[0].currentTime = 0; //play audio

        } else { // play audio
          setTimeout(function() { //play audio
            $("#notify")[0].play(); //play audio
          })
        }; //play audio

        //--------------------

        localStorage.setItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1', 'true')
      }

    } else if (!total) {
      $('#regalo').hide();
      $('#alert').show();
    } else {
      console.log("FAIL");
      $('#alert').hide();
      $('#regalo').hide();
    }
  }

  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.bbp')) {
      manageRegalo();

      localStorage.setItem('total', Number($("#total").val()));
    }
  });
  manageRegalo();
});
```

```css
#alert,
.tooltip {
  display: none
}

@media screen and (max-width:999px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  #alert {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="regalo">REGALO</div>

<div class="tooltip">Tooltip</div>

<div id="alert">ALERT</div>

<input type="text" id="total" value="0">
<button type="button" class="bbp">Enter</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es la precedencia de estilos.

Por un lado tienes los estilos en CSS en un hoja de estilos aparte, y por otro estás haciendo `.hide()`/`.show()` en JavaScript. jQuery aplica los estilos inline (p.e. `.hide()` añadirá `style="display:none"` y `.show()` añadirá `style="display:block"`), y al estar inline van a tener precedencia sobre los de la hoja de estilos. Por eso la regla que tienes en el CSS no se está aplicando como esperas.

Una posible solución sería añadir/quitar clases con JavaScript/jQuery. De ese modo, todos los estilos estarán en la hoja de estilos y podrás controlar mejor qué regla se va a aplicar. Así por ejemplo, cuando el `#alert` deba estar visible, puedes poner una clase que sea `.alert-visible` y cuando deba estar oculto le pones `.alert-oculto`.

Ésta es una versión simplificada de tu código (quitando las referencias a localStorage para que no de error) a la que le he añadido las clases (usando [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)) en lugar de aplicar los estilos directamente con JS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function manageRegalo() {
    var total = parseFloat($("#total").val());

    if (!total) {
      $('#regalo').hide();
      $('#alert').toggleClass("alert-visible", true).toggleClass("alert-oculto", false);
    } else {
      console.log("FAIL");
      $('#alert').toggleClass("alert-visible", false).toggleClass("alert-oculto", true);
      $('#regalo').hide();
    }
  }

  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.bbp')) {
      manageRegalo();
    }
  });
  manageRegalo();
});
```

```css
#alert,
.tooltip {
  display: none
}

@media screen and (max-width:999px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  #alert,
  #alert.alert-visible {
    display: block;
  }
  
  #alert.alert-oculto {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="regalo">REGALO</div>

<div class="tooltip">Tooltip</div>

<div id="alert">ALERT</div>

<input type="text" id="total" value="0">
<button type="button" class="bbp">Enter</button>
```

Y un método similar podría utilizarse para el regalo. Aparte, estoy utilizando dos clases para visualizar mejor cuando debe estar visible u oculto. Pero puede simplificarse para usar una sola clase (`.alert-oculto`).

Comment: Una solucion elegante. Muchas gracias. +10